# разделение содержимого столбца

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DF:

```
Project name
0   ABC-ND-SON-Project-a
1   ABC-ND-SON-Project-a
2   ABC-ND-SON-Project-a
3   ABC-WD-SON-Project-b
4   ABC-WD-SON-Project-b
5   ABC-LI-SON-Project-c
6   ABC-LI-SON-Project-c
7   ABC-KD-SON-Project-d
8   ABC-KD-SON-Project-d
```

В нем мне нужно удалить первые 4 символа, чтобы избаваться от "ABC-" частей, потом для "LI-SON" и "KD-SON" проектов оставить только первые две части теста. Для проектов другого типа - оставить 3 части.

*Вот результат, к которому я хочу прийти:*

```
Project name
0   ND-SON-Project
1   ND-SON-Project
2   ND-SON-Project
3   WD-SON-Project
4   WD-SON-Project
5   LI-SON
6   LI-SON
7   KD-SON
8   KD-SON
```

Код:

```
import pandas as pd
df_list = pd.read_html('Table.html', match='Projects:')
df = pd.concat([df_list], axis=1) #датафрейм с изначальным списком

df['Project name'] = df['Project name'].str[4:] #удаление "ABC-" 
df = df['Project name'].str.split('-', 3,  expand=True)
cols = [0, 1, 2]
df['New'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: '-'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1) #новый столбец, в котором все Project names содержат только первые 3 части текста (без ABC-)
df = df.drop(columns=[0, 1, 2, 3])
print(df)
```

На даном этапе мне не получается убрать часть "-Project" только для LI и KD проектов:

```
New
0   ND-SON-Project
1   ND-SON-Project
2   ND-SON-Project
3   WD-SON-Project
4   WD-SON-Project
5   LI-SON-Project
6   LI-SON-Project
7   KD-SON-Project
8   KD-SON-Project
```

Я пытался убрать только для "LI":

```
def row(df):
    for k in df['New']:
        if k.startswith('LI'):
            k.str.split('-', 1)[0]
df['New'] = df['New'].apply(row)
```

Но выдает такую ошибку:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [66], in <module>
      3         if k.startswith('LI'):
      4             k.str.split('-', 1)[0]
----> 5 df['New'] = df['New'].apply(row)

Input In [66], in row(df)
      1 def row(df):
----> 2     for k in df['New']:
      3         if k.startswith('LI'):
      4             k.str.split('-', 1)[0]

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: abc- присутствует обязательно? если да то нужно применить пользовательскую функцию к столбцу

Comment: @ganz часть abc- я изначально убрал df['Project name'] = df['Project name'].str[4:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вы намудрили, мне кажется

```
df.loc[df["Project name"].str.contains("LI|KD")] = df.loc[df["Project name"].str.contains("LI|KD")].applymap(lambda x: "-".join(x.split("-")[1:3]))
df.loc[df["Project name"].str.contains("ABC")] = df.loc[df["Project name"].str.contains("ABC")].applymap(lambda x: "-".join(x.split("-")[1:4]))
```

df:

```
     Project name
0  ND-SON-Project
1  ND-SON-Project
2  ND-SON-Project
3  WD-SON-Project
4  WD-SON-Project
5          LI-SON
6          LI-SON
7          KD-SON
8          KD-SON
```

Comment: Спасибо @strawdog, все работает